# Type null character in terminal

Tags: linux, text, terminal

Is there a way to type the null character in the terminal?

I would like to do something like:

```
this is a sentence (null) test123
```

Answer (score 16):

In Linux, any special character can be literally inserted on the terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> followed by the actual symbol. `null` is usually `^@` where `^` stands for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and `@` for whatever combination on your keyboard layout that produces <kbd>@</kbd>.

So on my keyboard I do: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>@</kbd> and I get a `^@` symbol with a distinguished background color. This means it's a special character and not just `^` and `@` typed in.

**Edit:** Several years later and a few input variations implemented by different terminals using keyboard layouts that require pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> to access <kbd>@</kbd>.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>@</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> followed by <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>@</kbd> **without** releasing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> followed by <kbd>@</kbd> **without** releasing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> release <kbd>Shift</kbd> and re-press <kbd>Shift</kbd> keeping both <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> pressed followed by <kbd>v</kbd> and finally <kbd>@</kbd>. Seen in some terminals that implement a special input on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>.

Comment: You're talking about `Vim`. Asker's talking about the `Shell`. Vim is the only one that accepts the NUL combo, and is also the only one that colors its control chars.

Comment: @B1KMusic Sorry but no, I'm not talking about `Vim`. I'm talking about plain `xterm`, both `bash` and `zsh`.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work in bash. Only zsh and vim. I tested it in tty, xterm, st, rxvt and gnome terminal.

Comment: Bash version 4.3.11, stock from Ubuntu repo

Comment: I did just fine a weird quirk, though. If you run, e.g. `while true; do true; done` and then hit `Ctrl + Space` while you don't have control, it will print null characters. Not really useful, but interesting behavior nonetheless

Comment: Typically Ctrl-Space enters a null character -- depending on the terminal emulator. But I've just run into a problem where xterm under Ubuntu 14.04.03 LTS doesn't recognize either Ctrl-Space or Ctrl-@ (no input is generated for either). But it works under Linux Mint 17.1 and 17.2. Still trying to track down the cause. (I use ^@ as the command character for `screen`.)

Comment: @BradenBest `bash` has nothing to do with it -- it's the terminal that reads input and sends the key codes. `bash` may be ignoring it, but pretty much every terminal in existence sends `NUL` for Ctrl+@. Run `showkey -a` and try it.

Comment: @CraigBarnes appreciated, but... three years. Just saying. I've already known about that for a while, and frankly don't even remember writing the above comments.

Comment: No worries. Just thought I'd clarify for anyone else who finds this comment and gets the impression that using Ctrl+@ to send `NUL` isn't portable.

Comment: So there's no way to get this working on gnome-terminal? @BradenBest I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.3 and I tried all the methods mentioned in the answer, every key combo you can think of, but it didn't work.

Comment: I can't even get a gnome-terminal running at the moment (which is fine because I prefer [st](https://st.suckless.org/) anyway), so I dunno what to tell you.

Answer (score 10):

```
$ echo -e "this is a sentence \0 test123"
this is a sentence  test123
```

<kbd>`The null here    ^^    IS NOT visible`</kbd>

```
$ echo -e "this is a sentence \0 test123" | cat --show-nonprinting
this is a sentence ^@ test123
```

<kbd>`But it IS here    ^^`</kbd>

But maybe you did not want this for a script?

Answer (score 7):

Apparently you can type this character with ^@ on some character sets. [This wikipedia article on the null character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) may be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

As with the abort command (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>), in most terminals just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>@</kbd> (with the use of <kbd>Shift</kbd> on my keyboard).

Comment: I confirm - in my case, the @ needs the "graphics alt" AltGr key, so Ctrl+AltGr+@ does the trick.