# How to specify NUL-terminated names of files for wc --files0-from=F

Tags: string, wc, nul

I need to test wc with  --files0-from=F  flag,  but I don't know how to write a file that contains NUL-terminated file names?
Whatever I try, it merges the file names together and outputs:

```
wc: '1.txt2.txt': No such file or directory
wc: '1.txt 2.txt': No such file or directory
wc: '1.txt\02.txt': No such file or directory
```

How do I write the NUL-terminator?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you can't. NUL-terminated filenames are the output of another program. What I did is put all the files I need in one folder, then execute this command there:

```
find * -print0 > feed.txt
```

So feed.txt now has file names separated by NUL character, which is what I need to execute this successfully.

```
wc --files0-from=feed.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes I have test the way @ivanacorovic said and it works.

> -print0 is must, and -print does not work.

---

BTW.
Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572801/type-null-character-in-terminal), I have found the way to type out `NUL-terminated` NUL.
`^@` is NUL, however it is not the combination of `@`and `^`.
The right way to type it is:
`Ctrl+v` followed by `Ctrl+Shift+@`
Actually you can see the `^@` through vim by `-print0` option.

Comment: In zsh, control @ does yield null.  I have tried it for `du` that uses the same option `--files0-from=`.